# Call method from within Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, methods

If I have the query below :-

```
var Values = from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
            group data by new
            {
                InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
                AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
            }
            into g
            select new
            {
                Code = "1",
                InvType = "I",
                Account = g.Key.AccRef,
                InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
                ChargeType = ***********
            };
```

...how I can I call a separate method CalcChargeType (which returns a string, based on the value in the InvNo column) and have the returned value go into column ChargeType, as, from what I've read, methods cannot be translated into Linq/SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> from what I've read, methods cannot be translated into Linq/SQL.

But you are not using `Linq-To-Sql` but `Linq-To-DataSet` which is  a subset of `Linq-To-Objects`.

So yes, you can do all that you can do without Linq, f.e. calling a method:

```
var Values = from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
        group data by new
        {
            InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
            AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
        }
        into g 
        select new
        {
            Code = "1",
            InvType = "I",
            Account = g.Key.AccRef,
            InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
            ChargeType = CalcChargeType(g.Key.InvNo)
        };
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for this, and to the others that answered.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ?

```
var Values = from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
            group data by new
            {
                InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
                AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
            }
            into g
            select new
            {
                Code = "1",
                InvType = "I",
                Account = g.Key.AccRef,
                InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
                ChargeType = CalcChargeType(g.Key.InvNo)
            };
```

The, when you will evaluate the query (with `ToList()` for example), `CalcChargeType` will be called/

Answer (score 2):

Since this is not Linq to SQL you may call it without problems.

By casting the first part of query to `.AsEnumerable()` you have fetched all data in the `tblCosts` table to the memory. Now it is not a Linq to SQL query, but an in memory linq query.

Comment: `AsEnumerable` does not "fetch all data to the memory". Actually he uses `DataSets` which are allready in memory. [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) just enables to use `Linq` since a `DataTable` does not implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>` by nature.

Comment: @TimSchmelter then this behavior is different than objectcontext / dbcontext behavior of entity framework.

Comment: @dayal: Linq-To-DataSet _is_ Linq-To-Objects. It's all already in memory. It's rather different to Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks. I will not delete the answer considering the useful information included.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to **evaluate** the query (by calling `.ToList()`), then re-select and call the function, like so:

```
var Values = (from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
        group data by new
        {
            InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
            AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
        }
        into g)
        .ToList()
        .Select(g => new
        {
            Code = "1",
            InvType = "I",
            Account = g.Key.AccRef,
            InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
            ChargeType = CalcChargeType(g.Key.ChargeType)
        };
```

Comment: This is not true. You can call every method you want in a Linq-To-Objects query without calling `ToList`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Apologies, my assumption was that it *wasn't* Linq to Objects

Answer (score 1):

Well you could *try*:

```
var Values = from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
        group data by new
        {
            InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
            AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
        }
        into g
        select new
        {
            Code = "1",
            InvType = "I",
            Account = g.Key.AccRef,
            InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
            ChargeType = CalcChargeType(g.Key.InvNo)
        };
```

Since you're using DataSet extensions and not Linq-to-SQL I bet it would work.  If your Linq provider doesn't support it, your next bet is to hydrate what you can and add the ChargeType column afterwards:

```
var Values = (from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
        group data by new
        {
            InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
            AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
        }
        into g).ToList() // hydrate the query
        .Select(g=> new
        {
            Code = "1",
            InvType = "I",
            Account = g.Key.AccRef,
            InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
            ChargeType = CalcChargeType(g.Key.InvNo)
        });
```